# Dealing with static libraries when porting C code from one operating system to another

Tags: c, linux, windows, compilation

I have been working on some C code on a windows machine and now I am in the process of transferring it to a Linux computer where I do not have full privileges.  In my code I link to several static libraries.

**Is it correct that these libraries need to be re-made for a Linux computer?**

The library in question is GSL-1.13 scientific library

Side question, does anyone have a pre-compiled version of the above for Linux?

I have tried using automake to compile the source on the Linux machine, but no makefile seems to be created and no error is output.

Thanks

Comment: What do you do exactly, dir listing, what Linux machine, tried using a VM for compiling library X? – this lacks info...

Comment: Depending on the Linux distribution, a premade package might be available for GSL (or at least some other easy-packaging solution). Additionally, the C runtime may differ between systems, and therefore your static packages (which more than likely employ the C runtime) would need to be compiled per-system.

That all said, while this question doesn't really *lack* the necessary information to have someone provide a prescriptive response, it would be nice for you to add in your compiler, system, and other environment-based information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do need to compile any library again when you switch from Windows to GNU/Linux.

As for how to do that, you don't need automake to build GSL. You should read the file INSTALL that comes inside the tarball (the file gsl-1.16.tar.gz) very carefully. In a nutshell, you run the commands

```
$ ./configure
$ make
```

inside the directory that you unpacked from the tarball.

Comment: If you don't have root privilege I would suggest instead `./configure --prefix=$HOME/soft`  (and also add `$HOME/soft/bin` to your `PATH`).